# Extracting max row from dataframe into a tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from which I need to extract a tuple from the row with the highest value in the field "% Renewable".

I am using this...

```
def answer_six():
    maxRenew = answer_one()
    maxRenew = maxRenew[['% Renewable']].loc[maxRenew['% Renewable'].idxmax()]

    return(tuple(zip(maxRenew.index, maxRenew)))
```

and the output is

```
(('% Renewable', 69.64803),)
```

while I need

```
('Brazil',69.64803)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.[Screenshot of the df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLxMw.png)

Comment: What you are doing here is `maxRenew[['% Renewable']]....` taking a series of dataframe maxRenew and assigning it to maxRenew itself. Hence you have % Renewable as index. Instead have you tried using maxRenew.loc[maxRenew['% Renewable'].idxmax()] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the row-index of the maximum value, you can use it to get the element you want out of the index:

```
idxmax = maxRenew['% Renewable'].idxmax()

return (maxRenew.index[idxmax],maxRenew.loc[idxmax,'% Renewable'])
```

Comment: That worked well thanks although I tweaked the return to...

    return (idxmax,maxRenew.loc[idxmax,'% Renewable'])